# Showing that $P\left(-\frac{K}{2}<S_n<\frac{K}{2}, \text{ for all }n \geq 1 \right)=0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

We fix ourselves $(X_n, n\geq 1)$ a family of i.i.d random variables such that $P(X_1=1)=\frac{1}{2}, P(X_1=-1)=1-\frac{1}{2}$. We fix $S_0=0$ and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ for all $n \geq 1$.

Knowing that $A_n=\{X_{nK+1}=\cdots=X_{(n+1)K}\}, n \geq 1$ is realise almost infinitly often, I have to show that :

$$
P\left(-\frac{K}{2}<S_n<\frac{K}{2}, \text{ for all }n \geq 1 \right) = 0 $$

And then show that $$P\left(\{\limsup S_n=+\infty\} \cup \{\liminf S_n = - \infty\}\right)=1$$

However, the correction say that $$\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\{-\frac{K}{2}<S_n<\frac{K}{2}\right\} \subset \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} A_n^c$$

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

If $-\frac K 2<S_n<\frac K 2$ for all $n$ then $|S_{(n+1)K}-S_{nK}|\leq |S_{(n+1)K}|+|S_{nK}|<\frac K 2+\frac K 2=K$. But this means

$|X_{nK+1}+...+X_{(n+1)K}|<K$. If the terms on the left are all equal, then the sum will either $K$ of $-K$, leading to a  contradiction.